# VideoJS how to reset video, show poster and play button

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm using the [VideoJS](http://videojs.com) plugin and I cannot figure out how to reset a video so that the user sees the poster and the play button again after it has ended.

I have tried :

```
$('#video_id').on("ended", function () {
      $(this).paused = false; // didnt work
      $(this).paused(false); // didnt work
      $(this).currentTime = 0; // didnt work
      $(this).reset(); // didnt work
});
```

But none of this works. Please help...

Comment: try removing the video element from the DOM and adding it again.

Comment: That was a nice idea, unfortunately the video plugin didnt initialize itself after removing and adding it from the DOM

Answer (score 2):

As posted [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2661), nowdays best method is to set `hasStarted` player prop to `false`. I tested it myself and it works. And it does not need to be on video ended.

@st80 answer did not work for me.

```
videojs_instance.hasStarted(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

```
$(video).on("ended", function () {
    var videoElem = document.getElementById('videoDiv');
    videojs(videoElem).trigger('loadstart');
});
```

For showing the playButton and poster again, it is possible by modifying the CSS

that did the trick! :-)